# Start a new thread using an Action instance

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

How do I start a new thread using an action object in VB.NET?

```
_taskopts.AddTask(1, AddressOf MyMethod, "Test Task", True)
```

...

```
Public Sub AddTask(minfreq As Double, subroutine As Action, name As String, immediate As Boolean)
    If minfreq > 0 Then
        Dim task As New TaskObj With {.minfreq = minfreq, .subroutine = subroutine, .name = name}

        If immediate Then
            task.lastrun = New Date(1970, 1, 1)
        Else
            task.lastrun = Now()
        End If

        _tasks.Add(task)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ExecuteTasks()
    For Each task As TaskObj In _tasks
        Try
            TaskOp(task)
        Catch ex As Exception
            InvokeMessage("TaskOpts Execute Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TaskOp(ByRef task As TaskObj)
    If Now.Subtract(task.lastrun).TotalMinutes > task.minfreq Then
        task.lastrun = Now()

        Dim taskthread As New Thread(AddressOf task.subroutine) '*****ERROR HERE*****   
        taskthread.Start()

        Thread.Sleep(100)
    End If
End Sub
```

This causes the error: "AddressOf operand must be the name of a method." I'm thinking maybe I need to use something other than an Action object, maybe some way of passing AddressOf through the AddTask sub.

Answer (score 0):

In the TaskOp sub where you have the compilcation error pass a collection of tasks or add the tasks you have to execute in there. The example below shows how to pass an integer parameter to the function. You can pass other parameters according to your needs.

```
 Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            Dim temp_i As Integer = i
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(Function() CallYourFunction(temp_i)))
        Next
        Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
```